# Retrieve rows from table via function

Tags: oracle, function

What I want to do : Retrieve data from a table using Custom function and using Custom Types.

The Structure of my table is like below :

```
create table ACCOUNTCONTRACT
(
  accountcode_            VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  accountmig_             NUMBER(1),
  accountnumber_          VARCHAR2(25 CHAR) not null,
  accountpk_              NUMBER(19),
  addinfo1_               VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  addinfo2_               VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
...
```

What I Did :  Create my Custom Types

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "FO_OUTPUT" AS OBJECT
(
  NUMCPT        VARCHAR2(10),
  ACTIONACCOUNT VARCHAR2(50)
)
```

AND

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "FO_OUTPUT_TABLE" AS TABLE OF FO_OUTPUT
```

My Function is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OUTPUT_FO RETURN FO_OUTPUT_TABLE AS
  RETVAL  FO_OUTPUT_TABLE := FO_OUTPUT_TABLE();
  TMPLINE FO_OUTPUT;
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN (SELECT SUBSTR(ACC.ACCOUNTNUMBER_, 1, 10) AS NUMCPT,
                   ACC.ACCOUNTNUMBER_ AS ACTIONACCOUNT
              INTO TMPLINE.NUMCPT, TMPLINE.ACTIONACCOUNT
              FROM ACCOUNTCONTRACT ACC
             WHERE ROWNUM < 10) LOOP

    RETVAL.EXTEND;
    RETVAL(RETVAL.COUNT) := TMPLINE;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN(RETVAL);
END OUTPUT_FO;
```

Now When I execute : `SELECT * FROM TABLE (OUTPUT_FO) All I got is a 10 empty rows.

What is wrong with my code. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OUTPUT_FO RETURN FO_OUTPUT_TABLE AS RETVAL FO_OUTPUT_TABLE := FO_OUTPUT_TABLE();
TMPLINE FO_OUTPUT;
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  TMPLINE := FO_OUTPUT('', ''); 
  FOR I IN (SELECT SUBSTR(ACC.ACCOUNTNUMBER_, 1, 10) AS NUMCPT,
                   ACC.ACCOUNTNUMBER_ AS ACTIONACCOUNT
              --INTO TMPLINE.NUMCPT, TMPLINE.ACTIONACCOUNT << this does not work
              FROM ACCOUNTCONTRACT ACC
             WHERE ROWNUM < 10) LOOP

    -- But this:                 
    TMPLINE.numcpt:= i.numcpt;
    TMPLINE.ACTIONACCOUNT:= i.ACTIONACCOUNT;

    RETVAL.EXTEND;
    RETVAL(RETVAL.COUNT) := TMPLINE;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN(RETVAL);
END OUTPUT_FO;
```

Comment: I confused the use of  "select Into". had to initialize the composite type.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BULK COLLECT INTO`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OUTPUT_FO
RETURN FO_OUTPUT_TABLE
AS
  RETVAL  FO_OUTPUT_TABLE;
BEGIN
  SELECT FO_OUTPUT(
           SUBSTR(ACC.ACCOUNTNUMBER_, 1, 10),
           ACC.ACCOUNTNUMBER_
         )
  BULK COLLECT INTO RETVAL
  FROM   ACCOUNTCONTRACT ACC
  WHERE  ROWNUM < 10;

  RETURN RETVAL;
END OUTPUT_FO;
/
```

Comment: considering speed and performance, Does BULK is more efficient and faster then the code that I wrote in the answer section?

Comment: It [appears that Oracle](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2353407?start=0&tstart=0) will (internally) convert a cursor `FOR` loop to a bulk collect (if it can). So there may be little difference in performance but you can also compare whether the code is simpler (to read and to maintain). The simplest method for finding which is more performant is to actually profile it on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I did to get it work :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OUTPUT_FO RETURN FO_OUTPUT_TABLE AS
  RETVAL  FO_OUTPUT_TABLE := FO_OUTPUT_TABLE();
BEGIN
  FOR I IN (SELECT SUBSTR(ACC.ACCOUNTNUMBER_, 1, 10) AS NUMCPT,
                   ACC.ACCOUNTNUMBER_ AS ACTIONACCOUNT
              FROM ACCOUNTCONTRACT ACC
             WHERE ROWNUM < 10) LOOP

    RETVAL.EXTEND;
    RETVAL(RETVAL.COUNT) := FO_OUTPUT(I.NUMCPT, I.ACTIONACCOUNT);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN(RETVAL);
END OUTPUT_FO;
```

Comment: in this case `TMPLINE` is not required.